# -didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When I click the UITableViewCell , It have selection effect (grey background in clicked cell),But `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not calling  ,what happen?

**EDIT**

this is my code

tableView.h file

```
@interface PopCardView : MMPopupView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

tableView.m file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tagsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView         *backView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView    *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger     lastIndex;

@end

-(id)initWithTags:(NSMutableArray *)tags{
    self = [super init];

if (self) {
  self.backView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  self.backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
  self.backView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

  [self addSubview:self.backView];

  [self.backView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.left.top.bottom.right.equalTo(self);
  }];

  _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 324, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  _tableView.tableFooterView =[[UIView alloc] init];
  [self.backView addSubview:_tableView];
  [_tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
     make.left.top.right.bottom.equalTo(self.backView).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(45,0, 45, 15));
     make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(324, 200));
  }];

  [_tableView registerClass:[PopCardTagViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

  _tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
  _tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
  [_tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


  _tableView.dataSource = self;
  _tableView.delegate = self;

  }
  return self;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_tagsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        PopCardData *data = (PopCardData *)obj;
        data.selected = @"0";
        if (idx == indexPath.row) {
            data.selected = @"1";
        }
    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}




-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifer = @"cell";
    PopCardTagViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifer];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PopCardTagViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifer];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(void)configureCell:(PopCardTagViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PopCardData *data = (PopCardData *)[_tagsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //configure cell
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _tagsArray.count;
}
```

**EDIT2**

this is my initialize code of PopCardView,it use swift

```
let pop = PopCardView(tags: self.m_model.getItmes())
pop.show()
```

Comment: Can you post `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function?

Comment: Show us your tableview rendering code?

Comment: did you set the `UITableView` delegate (either via storyboard or by code)?

Comment: rendering code? you mean is code for UITableViewCell?  @Vijay

Comment: @anhtu I have add it edit

Comment: @jansma Thank, did you set delegate for `UITableView` ?

Comment: @jansma Sorry, but how do you know it doesn't call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? Do you use breakpoint? Don't see anything go wrong with your code.

Comment: @anhtu yes I use breakpoint

Comment: @jansma `@interface ClassName ()<UITableViewDelegate>`? Did it? So weird

Comment: @jansma Can you please post more code relate to `tableView`?

Comment: @anhtu I have update my code

Comment: @jansma Maybe the problem is the instance of `PopCardView`. Can you please post the code where you initialize and show the instance of `PopCardView`. Maybe it's released.

Comment: @anhtu intialize code is update in edit2  and the instance of `PopCardView` is initWithTags function

Comment: @jansma. Thank you. I don't see anything goes wrong here. :).

Answer (score 0):

The code you show does not set any delegate to the table view. Either this is the reason or you posted an incomplete code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

and add UITableViewDelegate to your interface like

```
@interface ClassName ()<UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: The answer is previous to the author edit, but he's already doing it in the posted code.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you don't have anything in the cell that can swallow the touch event. Things like buttons and textfields can cause this. Strip everything from your cell, test to see if it works, then add things back in slowly to find the culprit.